# How can I make text wrap down to the next line, when a user reduces the size of the browser?

Tags: html, css

Noob question, for my website, how can I make the text layout change with the size of the browser?

So if a line of text fits straight across a the browser on a big monitor, then someone reduces the size of the browser (or opens up the site on a phone), I want the text to move down to the next line.

Comment: use word-wrap:normal or word-wrap:break-word;

Comment: Pretty sure this happens as default anyway?

Comment: Hmm, well it's not happening for me. If I resize the browser, the text is not wrapping. I wonder if I did something to cancel it out?

Comment: If you could give us a link, it'd be easier to track down the problem

Comment: Sorry Bobo, the site is not up yet. Thanks for the offer though.

Comment: You probably have a fixed width set on some containing element to that text.  If you set a fixed width that is wider than the user's screen, the text won't wrap to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Keith, you can use:

```
word-wrap: normal;
```

or

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Neither of these worked for me. Neither did `word-break: break-all;` I guess must be doing something that is preventing this from working.