# How can I get the hero text to resize itself when shrinking the browser down to iPhone size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have hero-text that does not resize properly as I shrink the size of the browser. Like so:

[image]

I tried the suggestion of the SO post here:
[How can I make text wrap down to the next line, when a user reduces the size of the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065134/how-can-i-make-text-wrap-down-to-the-next-line-when-a-user-reduces-the-size-of)

but that did not work for me. This is my style.css file section regarding the hero section:

```
/* === HERO === */

#hero
{
    background: url("/wp-content/themes/threegreenbirds-daniel/images/grass-ground-new.jpg") 50% 0 repeat fixed;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.col-sm-7 {
    text-align: center;
}

.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

and this is the content-hero.php file:

```
<!-- HERO
==========================================================================  -->
<section id="hero" data-type="background" data-speed="5">
   <article>
      <div class="container clearfix">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7 hero-text">
              <h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1> 
              <p class="lead"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div><!-- container -->
   </article>
</section><!-- hero -->
```

I have tried with a class of col-sm-7 and word-wrap:normal and I have tried with a class of .col-sm-7.hero-text { word-wrap:normal} and neither has worked for me.

I did try this for tablet size:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .hero-text {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 130px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
    }
}
```

and it worked, but for iphone size the letters are still cut off despite having this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .hero-text {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 130px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
      }
}
```

Is it that 568px is not the right size? Why does it not work on smartphone size?

I then decided to keep .hero-text within the layout flow per the suggestion below and I developed this:

```
#hero
{
    background: url("/wp-content/themes/threegreenbirds-daniel/images/grass-ground-new.jpg") 50% 0 repeat fixed;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.container-clearfix {
    position: relative;
}

.col-sm-7 {
    text-align: center;
}

.hero-text {
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
    margin-top: 90px;
}

/* === MEDIA QUERIES === */

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .hero-text {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 130px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .logged-in .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 42px;
    }
    .hero-text {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 130px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .hero-text {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 130px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
      }
}
```

but what I have above has not worked when I reduce the screen size below 991px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned the benefits of using ems (or rems) when wanting the .hero-text to resize or adjust itself to the size of the screen. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
/* === MEDIA QUERIES === */

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .hero-text {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 90%;
        margin-top: 130px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 728px) {
    .hero-text {
        font-size: 75%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 648px) {
    .logged-in .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 42px;
    }
    .hero-text {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 75%;
        margin-top: 130px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .hero-text {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 50%;
        margin-top: 130px;
        background: none;
      }
}
```

By choosing font-size: 90% and repeating this for other viewport sizes and adjusting appropriately, I was able to get the text to resize itself when changing viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you took `.hero-text` out of the normal layout flow with `position:absolute`.

Not entirely sure how your text is supposed to look like in the end but you have 2 choices:

1. add `position: relative` to either `#hero` or `.container`. This will make the absolute positioned layer be positioned relative to those layers. Right now I would assume it's positioned relative to the `body` since you don't have `position: relative` on any parent of `.hero-text`

or

2. don't take `.hero-text` out of layout flow and try to get the style you want without using `position: absolute` on it

Comment: I have tried adding position: relative to the #hero and to the .container-clearfix, but neither worked. Could you explain what you mean by not taking .hero-text out of layout flow? Perhaps option 2 might work.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean by taking .hero-text out of the normal layout flow with position:absolute.

Comment: So I tried option too as well and although I will keep .hero-text within the layout flow, the style I am trying to get is that the .hero-text resizes itself to fit within the browser once I go below 991px. I will demonstrate what I have tried and not worked above.